# Selecting by bounding box with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a large dataset in a PostGIS database. I am viewing it via a web interface that loads the data as GeoJSON. There is too much data to give the client all at once (10s of MBs worth...) so I would like to get an area of data within the bounding box formed by the edges of the window (the dotted line in the image below). Getting the coordinates for points f and g is easy.

**Question 1:** Is this a good way of doing things? Should I be thinking of caching them as tiles or is this method likely to be efficient enough?

**Question 2:** How do I retrieve just the data within this bounding box?

**Question 3:** If a shape overlaps the edge of the bounding box (e.g. shape A below) is there a simple way to crop it as it is queried like in the second image?

[image]

Comment: Which viewer are you running on the client?

Comment: Mapstraction. I'm currently using OpenLayers as the provider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just change the order of the questions and you have a procedure:

2)Select only what intersects the bbox (`ST_Intersects`).
3)Intersect it with the bbox to clip the polygons (`ST_Intersection`).
1)Create a new table with the results (`CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT...`).

[ST_Intersection docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) contain a code sample. You will need to adapt it and use [ST_PolygonFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PolygonFromText.html) as the bbox.

Answer (score 4):

I think most (all) web-clients (and desktop gis too)  is doing this. You cannot send the whole dataset.

If you should set up some sort of caching depends on if your data is vary static or if it is changing.

To make this bounding box check to get the data will be very fast (if you have a spatial index), but of course it is not for free. You will pay with some cpu-power.

As said before:
To find the polygons inside your extent you use ST_Intersects.

To get only the portion inside your extent use ST_Intersection,
but don't do that. ST_Intersection is a costly process. Unless you have extremely big polygons I think it is better to send the whole polygons.

But I guess you want to do this on the fly instead of putting it in a table