# OpenGeo/GeoServer WFS - getting only as much data as is needed

Tags: geoserver, geoext, boundless-suite

There's probably a term for this that I'm missing that would help me find the answer...

My question is similar to a [previous question of mine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/selecting-by-bounding-box-with-postgis). I am using GeoServer (as part of the OpenGeo stack) as a WFS server. Currently when I load my map it downloads the entire layer - roughly 10MB per layer, roughly 10 layers...it takes a while.

I would like it to work in the way that WMS does - only download enough to show what is needed.

I need to use WFS rather than WMS as I need to be able to click on polygons, edit their attributes etc.

Is there a word for this?

Is it possible with GeoServer/OpenGeo/GeoExt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's what [OpenLayers BoundingBox strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) is good for.

> A simple strategy that reads new features when the viewport invalidates some bounds.

If it's in OpenLayers, it should be available in GeoExt too.

Comment: Perfect! That's just what I was looking for and I only had to change one line of code! Only problem now is that it isn't obvious when it is loading data and when it is finished...any ideas?

Comment: Live Example (though tiles not rendering correctly - http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-bbox.html ) but can view source how to implement your BBOX.