# Find all of the ways that intersect a linestring

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I'm new to Open Street Map and PostGIS, and am trying to figure out how to
find all of the ways that intersect a linestring (i.e. all of the streets that
intersect a route).  Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve calling
ST_Intersects on every row of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is only checking for intersecting within a bounding box. See: [Selecting by bounding box with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/selecting-by-bounding-box-with-postgis)

Comment: Just to be clear: you're not saying that `ST_Intersects` and intersection with the BB are the same thing; you're simply suggesting making a preliminary selection based on intersection with the BB and following that up with the `ST_Intersects` tests, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was newyear night and i drank a lot of champagne. I could have been a little bit more elaborate.

Comment: ST_Intersects makes a bbox (if possible index-based) first selection before doing the "real" computation.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting all of the lines that intersect the linestring's bounding box and then used `ST_DWithin` to find the intersections.

Comment: I find it a bit weird to use ST_DWithin for your needs. Do you check on distance = 0?