# Select bounding box using postGIS?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, vector, osmosis, extents

I want to create a query to select all ways and their nodes that exist within a bounding box using postGIS. The bounding box shall includes all details as osmosis "--bounding-box" command will retrieves.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For the osmosis docs, [I see the command option](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Extracting_bounding_boxes):

```bash
--bounding-box top=49.5138 left=10.9351 bottom=49.3866 right=11.201
```

for PostGIS you can use [ST_MakeEnvelope(left, bottom, right, top, srid)](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) to build a bounding box, then the [`&&` bounding box operator](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) to find where the bounding boxes intersect:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(10.9351, 49.3866, 11.201, 49.5138, 4326);
```

The SRID 4326 is for WGS84 Lat/Long, and is only required for PostGIS 1.5; it can be omitted for later versions.

Comment: Thanks. the ST_MakeEnvelope function needs one more parameter, srid. I don't know what to put there.. any idea?

Comment: Looks like you are using PostGIS 1.5, which requires that parameter. I think that SRID is ignored, so any value might yield the same results. If you have lat/long data, generally use an SRID of 4326.

Comment: Most tools these days let you let you choose the SRID for OSM data when you load it.  The default OSM SRID is 3857 (spherical mercator).  The default SRID for most lat/lon data is SRID 4326 (Lat/Lon AKA WGS84).

If you load the data with SRID 3857, for example, you will have to do a conversion from LAT/LON WGS84 into 3857:
ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(LON1, LAT1, LON2, LAT2, 4326),3857)

Some tools (like imposm3) currenly only support SRID 3857

Comment: Note the && operator does not transform SRIDs for you. Be sure the Envelope you make is in the same SRID as the test geometry, or else transform it yourself. http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2320

Comment: && operator is computationally slower than ST_Intersects

Answer (score 8):

I think it will be something like this:
The bounding box in PostGIS is created by

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((ulx uly, urx ury, llx llr, lrx lry, ulx uly))', <srid>)
```

The query will use ST_Intersection with a subquery.

```
SELECT bbox_nodes.id, bbox_nodes.tag, nodes_geom 
FROM (SELECT nodes.id, nodes.tag, 
   ST_Intersection(nodes.the_geom, 
      ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((ulx uly, urx ury, llx llr, lrx lry, ulx uly))', <srid> )).geom AS nodes_geom
   FROM nodes 
   WHERE ST_Intersects(nodes.the_geom, 
      ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((ulx uly, urx ury, llx llr, lrx lry, ulx uly))', <srid> )) AS bbox_nodes
WHERE ST_Dimension(bbox_nodes.nodes_geom)=0;
```

I more or less took this from [The PostGIS help pages](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)
A second query, on the ways table, designed similar to the above (but with ST_Dimension()=1 ) should get the ways.

HTH,
Micha

Comment: Hi, Thanks! what the srid? what shoul I need to insert in <srid>? and ".geom" (line 4) it seems to be invalid, it's should be there?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment from last week. The srid is the Coordinate Reference System code. i.e. 2039 for Israel. The .geom addition extracts the Geometry part of a "GeometryCollection. You might be right that it's not required here.

Answer (score 5):

there is a topic here which similar to your question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/selecting-by-bounding-box-with-postgis)...

> ST_Intersection — (T) Returns a geometry that represents the shared
>   portion of geomA and geomB. The geography implementation does a
>   transform to geometry to do the intersection and  then transform back
>   to WGS84.

1.you can also get some information [here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geometry_returning.html#st-intersection) about Geometry Constructing Functions.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(
  ST_Buffer('POINT(0 0)', 2),
  ST_Buffer('POINT(3 0)', 2)
));
```

[image: intersection]

2.Another information [here](http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet) about Intersects Intersection: PostGIS - ST_Intersects, ST_Intersection...

```
SELECT b.the_geom As bgeom, p.the_geom As pgeom, 
        ST_Intersection(b.the_geom, p.the_geom) As intersect_bp
    FROM buildings b INNER JOIN parcels p ON ST_Intersection(b,p)
    WHERE ST_Overlaps(b.the_geom, p.the_geom)
    LIMIT 1;
```

[image: intersection]

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment on @Micha's code.

The coordinate pairs for the `POLYGON` should follow a clockwise (or a counter clockwise) order : upper left, upper right, lower right, lower left, upper left again.

So, clockwise, the function call should be :

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((ulx uly, urx ury, lrx lry, llx llr, ulx uly))', <srid>)
```

Or counter clockwise :

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((ulx uly, llx llr, lrx lry, urx ury, ulx uly))', <srid>)
```