# PostGIS select by lat/long bounding box

Tags: postgis

I have a minLat, minLong, maxLat and maxLong from a box drawn on a map. Right now, my query to get all the points in the box looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM geomTable
WHERE (longitude BETWEEN minLon AND maxLon)
AND (latitude BETWEEN minLat AND maxLat)
```

I want to use the geometry column instead of lat/long columns to get the results.
 I tried this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat, 4326);
```

from this post: [Select bounding box using postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25797/select-bounding-box-using-postgis) but it is returning no results.

Does anyone have an example of how to select all the points within a box created by min and max lat/longs using geometry in postgis?

Comment: What version of PostGIS are you using?

Comment: My PostGIS is Version 2.0.1

Comment: are both geom columns in the same SRID?

Comment: I think I might be way off with my approach...I only have one geom column. It's SRID is 2223

Comment: @bl8rchk what is the table `geomTable` and field `mytable.geom`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your data is not in lat/lon, so you need to push your box into the coordinate space of your data:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
  mytable.geom && 
  ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat, 4326), 2223);
```