# How can I query a geometry field in PostGIS for line segments within a given lat/long bounding box?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, extents

In google maps, I want to use `map.getBounds()` and take those values and query my PostGIS instance for all line segments that intersect that range. I am doing something wrong. I tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pipeline_denorm
WHERE pipeline_denorm.wkb_geometry &&
ST_Transform(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(
        -121.76986352563478, 37.85809027719253, 
        -121.19308129907228, 38.07462286323802, 4326), 
    2223);
```

based on a little research. Unfortunately no results are being returned and I am certain there is data that should be being returned. These are LineStrings. Basically want any record that contains a point within the bounding box.

Comment: Double check the SRID of your geometry:  SELECT ST_SRID(pipeline_denorm.wkb_geometry) FROM pipeline_denorm LIMIT 1;  or look at the column type in pgAdmin

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you copied the SQL from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/60706/37413), but it is not clear that you need the ST_Transform to SRID of 2223. Use the SQL @kttii included in a comment, and replace the 2223 with that number.

The way you have it written with the [&& operator](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html), you are comparing bounding boxes rather than the line itself. This may give you unexpected results if a line curves around a lot. I suspect you would prefer [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html), so you would have something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pipeline_denorm
WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(pipeline_denorm.wkb_geometry,
     ST_MakeEnvelope(-121.76986352563478, 
                      37.85809027719253, 
                     -121.19308129907228, 
                      38.07462286323802, 
                      4326
                    )
                );
```

You only need to add the [ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) if the SRID of the wkb_geometry column is different than 4326.