# I would like to extract 'landuse' information from OSM data using postgis

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgis-2.0

I am trying to extract OSM land use information for a given bounding box in PostGIS. Using [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60700/postgis-select-by-lat-long-bounding-box) example I wrote my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM planet_osm_polygon 
WHERE 
  planet_osm_polygon.landuse && 
  ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(1.49464, 49.1963130, 1.628030, 49.287031, 4326), 32647);
```

Unfortunately it returns me an error:

> ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (1.49464 49.1963 0):
>   latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)

Comment: Are you sure your coordinates are stored in EPSG:32647? If you used osm2pgsql, they will be in EPSG:3857. Apart from that, EPSG:32647 does not cover 1.5E 49.2N

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in a wrong column I should take planet_osm_polygon.way not planet_osm_polygon.landuse

```
SELECT  * FROM planet_osm_polygon 
WHERE planet_osm_polygon.way && 
ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope( 2.3160604029813427 ,49.20365292898691, 2.317437943284213 ,49.204552967527086 , 4326), 900913)
```

Comment: Out of interest, does osm have comprehensive land use information?

Comment: What do you mean by 'comprehensive'? If you are refering to completeness it depends on the region of the map and provided  by annotaters detalization.

Comment: OK, that's good enough. That fails my definition of comprehensive, which is more or less based on online dictionary:"including or dealing with all or nearly all elements or aspects of something.
". Back to satellite image processing it is :-)