# Reading lines within Bounding box failed

Tags: postgresql, extents

I am developing an application to display OSM data. In my scenario I need to display the data for one entire country. So my approach is that I will load curresponding countries osm data to postGreSQL and fetch it back on demand.

I am providing the zoom facility here (from 0 - 19) and for each zoom  level I will query different data based on what need to be displayed at that zoom level and using a bounding box. I am new to this approach. As there exist experts here, **I would like to know how feasilible would be this approach in terms of performance?** (Ealrlier I try to use osm.pbf files and trying to read it dynamically and display; but it hit the performance badly.

My second question is: I tried to query all the lines within a given bounding box but it displays empty row as result. May I know what I am doing here now?

**SELECT * FROM public.planet_osm_line 
where ST_INTERSECTS(way ,ST_MakeEnvelope(1.4411000, 41, 1.4411530, 45));**

Neither the below query worked (I assume that I can give the lattitudes and longitudes here to define the bounding box here reference: [Select bounding box using postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25797/select-bounding-box-using-postgis))

**SELECT * FROM public.planet_osm_line 
where ST_INTERSECTS(way ,ST_MakeEnvelope(-180, -180, 180, 180));**

I tried the below query also to fetch some data in France area. But failed again

**SELECT * FROM public.planet_osm_line where ST_INTERSECTS(ST_Transform(way,4326) ,ST_MakeEnvelope(-73.3968207647942, 49.296681801433,-73.823777534737, 49.5751193739016));**

Please advise.

Comment: I got it solved. A small issue with the SRID value caused the trouble. The resultant query is as follows...

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(way,4326)) FROM public.planet_osm_line where ST_INTERSECTS(ST_Transform(way,4326) ,ST_MakeEnvelope(1.379100, 43.563600,1.498600, 43.635200,4326));