# Points within a box

Tags: postgis

I need to get all points within a box to display them in a flat map. The column in the database is a geographic point. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM asset a 
WHERE a.point::geometry && ST_MakeEnvelope(28.715242, -96.730798, 30.684093, -94.559248, 4326)
```

I have the following points already stored in the asset table.

```
SRID=4326;POINT(-95.9681015014648 29.8167991638184)
SRID=4326;POINT(-95.3429565429688 29.6000289916992)
SRID=4326;POINT(-94.9028167724609 29.3941402435303)
SRID=4326;POINT(-95.5656051635742 29.7831516265869)
SRID=4326;POINT(-95.385986328125 29.5799331665039)
SRID=4326;POINT(-93.7581100463867 29.4718837738037)
```

It won't give an error.  There are records inside that box, but it just simply won't return any records.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just no results? What v. are you using? I think you used to need to set the SRID in your St_MakeEnvelope constructor.

Comment: [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25797/select-bounding-box-using-postgis) says that ST_MakeEnvelope is specificed in (left,bottom,right,top,srid) order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the #1 most common issue: swap the axis order to be X/Y (lng/lat)

```
ST_MakeEnvelope(-96.730798, 28.715242, -94.559248, 30.684093, 4326)
```