# PostGIS SQL syntax for bounding box

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tiles, extents

I have the following query:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM (
    SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geometry)::json As geometry, 
            (
                select row_to_json(t) 
                from (
                    select name, type, admin_level
                ) t
            )
        As properties

    FROM osm_admin As lg 
) 

As fc;
```

This returns all data in table as GeoJSON.

How can I additionally restrict the results to only within the bounding box? (As the second image [below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/selecting-by-bounding-box-with-postgis?rq=1).)

I need to get full GeoJSON for a tile. The PostGIS data is probably in 3857, as it's OSM imported as pbf with `imposm3`.

[image]

---

Have tried this, as per Mark C's suggestion:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) 
    FROM (

        SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geometry)::json As geometry, 

        (SELECT row_to_json(t) 
            FROM (SELECT name, type, admin_level)
            WHERE the_geom && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-73.9980, 40.726), ST_Point(-73.995, 40.723)), 4326) 
            As t 
        )

        As properties

        FROM osm_admin As lg 
    ) 
As fc;
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 6: FROM (SELECT name, type, admin_level)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the actual intersection of the bounding box, then create a bounding box as a sub-query at the same level as the select from osm_admin, and take the intersection of this bbox with lg.geometry. Note the ST_Intersects also in the where clause.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
  FROM (
    SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Intersection(lg.geometry, bbox.geom))::json As geometry, 
            (
               SELECT row_to_json(t) 
                 FROM (
                      SELECT name, type, admin_level
                 ) t
            )
     As properties
  FROM 
      osm_admin As lg, 
      (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2d(ST_MakePoint(x1,y1),
                ST_MakePoint(x2,y2)), 3857) as geom) as bbox 
  WHERE ST_Intersects(lg.geom, bbox.geom)
) fc;
```

Comment: No errors, but doesn't return any data either?

Comment: Actually, had some issues with coordinates. Seems to work swell! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. There are other (shorter) ways of making a bounding box, of course, I just like the ST_MakeBox2d and ST_MakePoint approach.

Comment: Works great. If I wanted to add a `ST_Transform` in there, to use lat/lon instead of meters, could I do that?

Comment: Do you mean ST_Transform of the output? If, so, yes, as the osm and bbox will both be in 3587, you can just change to `ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transfrom(ST_Intersection(lg.geometry, bbox.geom), 4326))::json`

Answer (score 1):

Form [Here!](http://docs.cartodb.com/tips-and-tricks.html) it says ..

```
SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE the_geom && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-73.9980, 40.726), ST_Point(-73.995, 40.723)), 4326)
```

> Here, we use some of the same functions you have seen previously. The opperator, &&, always uses the bounding box of geometries, unlike ST_Intersects which uses the full shape of a geometry. This can greatly speed up your queries in cases where bounding box comparison is sufficient.

Untested, but give this a shot ..

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM (
    SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geometry)::json As geometry, 
        (
        SELECT name, type, admin_level, geometry FROM osm_admin As lg WHERE the_geom
          && ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(-73.9980, 40.726), ST_Point(-73.995, 
          40.723)), 4326)
        ) t
    )
) As fc;
```

You will need to add in your bonding box corners and may need to change the SRID.

Comment: Thanks for your input. See my edit. Tried your untested query also, but same error. How come the `ST_Intersects` syntax is not used? Thanks again!

Comment: I think I messed up the sub-query. I do not have a database free to test this on right now. Hopefully someone will comment with the right syntax, if not, I will have a Db free tomorrow and will correct it.

Comment: According to the CartoDb docs, the BB query is a lot faster than the Intersects.

Comment: I added the `WHERE` clause inside the `FROM` parenthesis', which worked. But I think it's returning too many results.

Comment: Also, properties now return as `null`.

Comment: Figured it out with the other answer. Thanks for your help!